# Woocommerce push customer email to dataLayer

Tags: woocommerce, google-tag-manager

I want to push the customers email address to dataLayer on the order page. This is used for Google Ads Enhanced Conversions

I have tried different solutions but nothing seems to work for me.

Any good suggestion or is it simply not possible to grab the email and push to dataLayer?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How exactly do you need to push it to the dataLayer?

Comment: Where is the email address provided? Is it on the same page or running within an iframe? Have you tried simply capturing the value from the form element and pushing that to your datalayer?

Comment: I haven't really been able to find any solutions. I tried some plugins, that give you some usefull dataLayer variables - just not the mail. I can tell you what I need: 

<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({
 'ec_mail': 'test@test.com',
 'ec_phone': '+4588888888'
});
</script>

The mail is not visible on the order confirmed page.

In other CMS they usually have some sort of shortcode for the mail etc. But I can't find anything for Woocommerce. But basically everyone running Google Ads should be doing this, so there must surely be a solution :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can inject a script on the thankyou page and push the email to the data layer this way:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_ec_mail' );
function add_ec_mail(){
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) :

        $order_id = absint( get_query_var('order-received') );

        if( get_post_type( $order_id ) !== 'shop_order' ) return; // Exit

        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        ?>
        <script>
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; window.dataLayer.push({ 'ecomm_mail': '<?php echo $order->get_billing_email(); ?>' });
        </script>
        <?php

    endif;
}
```

I've adjusted your `ec_mail` to `ecomm_mail` as it seems to be the current format.